# Unable to install jest using npm i jest

Tags: jestjs, automated-tests, node-modules, npm-install, ts-jest

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

This is the warning, I am getting. Can you help ?

Answer (score -1):

Try installing
npm install --save-dev jest